# Can you use find queries on GridFS using javascript API?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs

As I understand it, when you enter something into GridFS it gets entered into 2 different collections under the hood. One for the raw chunks of data and one for the meta data files.

Also from what I understand from MongoDB's documentation is that you can only retrieve a document from GridFS with an id or name.

```
var gs = new mongodb.GridStore(db, "test.png", "w", {
"content_type": "image/png",
"metadata":{
    "author": "Daniel"
},
"chunk_size": 1024*4
```

});

So what if I want to get a subset of documents from GridFS? For example what if I want all GridStores with:

> metadata: {author: "Daniel"}

Why can't I use standard mongo queries { field: somevalue } and retrieve documents that way?

Does anybody know how this can be done? I'm using the javascript API on node.js.

Comment: What kind of subset are you talking about? Please give us an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can query the `db.files` collection just like any other collection:

```
db.collection('fs.files')
  .find({ 'metadata.author' : 'Daniel' })
  .toArray(function(err, files) {
    if (err) throw err;
    files.forEach(function(file) {
      var gs = new mongodb.GridStore(db, file._id, 'r');
      ...
    });
  });
```

Although instead of plain `forEach` you may want to use [`async.each`](https://github.com/caolan/async#maparr-iterator-callback) or any of the other `async.*` methods.