# nodejs mongodb driver and GridFS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I'm using nodejs and the native mongodb driver v2.0.43 (latest as of 9/18/2015) and am having problems querying the db.fs.files collection. It is returning that fs is undefined yet I can use the mongo console and see the files that have been stored using db.fs.files.find().toArray(). Does anyone have any experience querying the db.fs.files collection via node using the mongodb driver?

thanks

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after doing a better google query I found this solution: [Can you use find queries on GridFS using javascript API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379415/can-you-use-find-queries-on-gridfs-using-javascript-api)

The gist is you have to use 'fs.files' as the collection name.

```
db.collection('fs.files').find().toArray();
```